# Converting data frame string to a vector

Tags: r

I have a simple R question. I am taking data from a file and collapsing it to a string but ideally, I like to store the data as a character vector.

Assuming the list input of

A
B
C

The code below generates the string "A,B,C"

```
list<-paste(listinput$V1, collapse=",")
```

but how do I convert this comma separated string to a character vector similar to

```
list<-c("A","B","C")
```

Comment: `strsplit(list, ",")[[1]]` ?

Comment: yep, strsplit did the trick... great, thanks David!

Comment: @user2900006 please add the strsplit suggestion that David suggested as an answer

Answer (score 0):

This request makes very little sense. The object returned from `listinput$V1` would be exactly what is requested. (So would the one returned from `paste(listinput$V1)` for that matter. You should show what the file looks like in an editor, and then you may get the advice needed to input the data properly.

Comment: Why did you put that as answer as it seems all you want is additional information/clarification?

Comment: I thought that I gave two answers to the narrow question, and then I suggested a revision to try to elicit a more fundamental approach. ( I don't _need_ more information but I thought there might _be_ more information.)